# How to edit client massage in Telegram using python?

Tags: python, telegram, edit

I need to edit last message sent with python. How can I do it?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import EditMessageRequest

# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = api_id
api_hash = api_hash
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='j'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)
    await client.send_message(event.chat_id,'dd')
    event.edit_massge("")

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

When I send a message I want the script to edit it to the text that I will enter.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import EditMessageRequest

# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = api_id
api_hash = api_hash
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='j'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)
    message = await client.send_message(event.chat_id, "hello")  # changed line
    await client.edit_message(event.chat_id, message, "hello!")  # changed line

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

In addition, you can only edit your own messages (just in case you want to edit a message from someone else)